# Loading css from static files in django not working

Tags: django, django-templates

This is what the file explorer looks like:

[image: this is what the file explorer looks like]

this is the html file

userController/templates/users/dashboard.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        /* loadint the css */
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/dashboard.css' %}">
```

demowebsite/settings.py

```
# STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'userController/static/')
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

the css file is not getting loaded, i cant tell where my problem is

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: open dev console on browser click to network refresh the page see 404 no found and click on it you will see details(response tab) like the file couldn't find and you will also see a URL that Django try to get the file from copy it and go to this URL to be sure that your file in this URL

Comment: I've read this and many other sources many times, i came here after along and exhausting research.

Comment: @enesislam its css it doesnt raise an error

Comment: @Hannonqaoud could you access your css file on the new tab?

Comment: @enesislam it doesnt even show, there is another css file for google fonts only.

Comment: If it is on github I will send you a pull request

Comment: @enesislam unfortunately it is not on github, but fortunately i got it to work, thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: @Hannonqaoud was an honor

Answer (score 1):

the structure of your static files should be like below , change your code like this

```
STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
]
```